# How to set cookies with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I have used this website for testing http://www.webpagetest.org 
and among some suggestions for optimization it suggests that i set cookies for my images & global css;

How do I set cookies with htaccess? I want to cookie the site logo and the global.css which is loaded in almost every page.

also I have read on the yahoo developers http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html, that it suggest that cookies should be limited to the bare minimum, in my case what would be the better performance enhancer?

There is a siginficant loading time for the css and the site logo, so I want to at the very least save those as cookies, but can I save the majority of my images/scripts as cookies as well?

Comment: Cookies are stored with the browser and _sent back_ to the server on every page request.  I don't think you want your users submitting your logo back to you on each page load - a cookie is not the solution here.

Comment: why would you want to store css and images in cookies? cookies have a limited size capacity, and browsers can cache css/images anyways - if they're not being stored properly by the browser, then check your cache settings. don't use cookies for somethign they're not designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies should only be used to track the user of website on their various visits. What you're looking for is caching, and caching is done through the browser and not with ".htaccess". The only thing you can do is to *stop* the browser from caching static content from your page, for details on that look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370896/what-is-the-proper-way-to-tell-the-browser-not-to-cache). Maybe you have set a very low expiry on your content and it is fetched every time.

Comment: I do not understand, if my logo image is cached, then why is it being loaded on every page refresh?

Comment: my htaccess should be caching correctly, this is the code ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year
 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
 
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

Comment: mod_rewrite or htaccess file *do not* do any caching. I think you're confusing mod_expire with mod_rewrite