# Office-js addin with Excel and Edge Webview - how to delete cache?

Tags: webview, office-js, microsoft-edge

We are developing an office-js javascript addin for Excel. We are testing the addin with sideloading in Excel on Windows. After updating Windows and Excel to new versions, the webview in Office/Excel has changed from IE to Edge. Now we need to delete the Edge browser cache in order to see the changes in the updated web service.

To completely reload a sideloaded office-addin, it was sufficient to delete the local storage and IE browser cache.
After updating to the Edge webview, we do not manage to clear the browser cache.

In IE, we could flush the local storage and browser cache this way:
del /q /s /f C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Caches 
del /q /s /f C:\Users\ username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
del /q /s /f C:\Users\ username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF

psexec.exe -l c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4359

Instead of psexec (sysinternals) we could as well delete the IE cache via the internet options dialog.

In order to delete the Edge cache, we tried 
del /q /s /f C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC
or by opening the Edge browser end delete the cache via the UI.

Unfortunately the Edge cache seems to be not completely deleted, the office addin does not completely show the changed contents from the web service.

Answer (score 6):

First - manually deleting is not a good practice - as @Rick Kirkham said use standard web techniques for proper caching.
If you want to do it the hard way - list the cached files for the **Edge WebViewHost** like this:

```
dir /s %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\#!123\INetCache\
```

This system directory is not visible.
To empty the contents I used:

```
del /s /f /q %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\#!123\INetCache\
```

In our case we are using **Azure App Service (IIS)** as server for our backend.
And we added the following web.config setting to let the client re-validate all cached files:

```
...
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="must-revalidate" />
    </staticContent>
...
```

Comment: Tried every other thing on the internet and that second command did the trick. Ta

Answer (score 1):

When developing, its a good idea to turn off client side caching. The details will depend on what kind of server you are using. In most cases, it involves adding certain headers to the HTTP Responses. I've used the following pattern in the past, but you should research each of these and understand their effects.

```
Cache-Control: "private, no-cache, no-store"
Pragma: "no-cache"
Expires: "-1"
```

Also, see this SO question: [What is the proper way to tell the browser not to cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370896/what-is-the-proper-way-to-tell-the-browser-not-to-cache).

Comment: Thanks a lot! We also have to think about what happens on customer's computers when the web service is updated and the manifest files remain the same. We now read a version number from the server, which we compare with the clientside stored version. If there is a difference, we add a random variable to each requested URL, which opens a new cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in Visual Studio, it seems that the real issue is not so much browser caching as it is VS deciding which files to deploy to the local IIS Express server, used for local testing/development, or to a remote web server for publishing. In many cases modified html and/or js files won't make it into the web deployment even if you also modify the web.config file.

The way I made this work consistently is I selected the web application project (in Solution Explorer), opened properties, clicked the "Package/Publish Web" tab and then under "Items to deploy" I selected "All files in this project".

Works fine for me!

Answer (score -2):

Try to refer the following steps to delete the Microsoft Edge browser data:

1. In Microsoft Edge, go to **More...**> **Settings**.
2. Click the **Privacy & Security**, select **Choose what to clear**.
3. Select the check box next to each data type you’d like to clear, and then select Clear.
4. If you’d like, turn the Always clear this when I close the browser setting to On.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Besides, when you are using F12 developer tools to debug the website, you could also use the Developer Storage Tools to check the stored data and delete them. More detail information, please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/storage).

Comment: Thanks a lot! We tried it in exactly this way. With Edge browser itself, this is working, but with Excel Edge webview and office-js, there still was some content in the cache. Now I discovered new Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview, which gives me the F12 developert tools when running an office-js addin in Excel.