# Can't clean cache in Edge WebView during Office Add-In Development

Tags: webview, microsoft-edge, office-addins

Now Office Add-Ins use new Edge based WebView instead IE 11 based one. From this moment, I can't develop anything. Because all files of the project can't be changed. Edge WebView always use cached versions of them.

I used many things.

```
<!-- Cache Control-->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<!-- No results. Absolutely. All content still cached-->
```

Also I've tried all things from here: 
[Office-js addin with Excel and Edge Webview - how to delete cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909922/office-js-addin-with-excel-and-edge-webview-how-to-delete-cache)

Also without success.

Now I use two 3 ways to proceed the "development".
     1. Change start point in the Manifest.xml. Every time after change something.
     2. Change port of the Web part of solution in files *.csproj and *.cproj.user. This also need to be done every try I change somethings in code.
     3. Wait for tomorrow after every change. Yes, it helps.

Where I'm wrong? Please help!

UPDATE: I've just learned about WebView2. I'm sure, I have usual  Edge WebView in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [Office-js addin with Excel and Edge Webview - how to delete cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909922/office-js-addin-with-excel-and-edge-webview-how-to-delete-cache)

In our case we are using **Azure App Service (IIS)** as backend for our Office AddIn.
And we added the following web.config setting to let the client re-validate all cached files on each access:

```
...
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="must-revalidate" />
    </staticContent>
...
```

Of course, the **cacheControlMaxAge** may be adjusted to your needs.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much. For my IIS Express I've just added these lines before the end of Web.Debug.config in the root of ...Web project (before </configuration>). And all things works now!