# Excel Web Addin not reflcecting any changes using Visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, office365, excel-web-addins

I am creating an **Excel web addin** using Visual studio, but when I am making any changes (adding any button or hiding an element) to my .html or .js they are not reflecting in excel or DOM Explorer files. I tried clearing cache, browser history. Nothing seems to be working out!
Please suggest!

Comment: Have you tried re-starting your web server running locally?

Comment: Try to clear the web view cache, see [Office-js addin with Excel and Edge Webview - how to delete cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909922/office-js-addin-with-excel-and-edge-webview-how-to-delete-cache/58553187#58553187) for more information.

Comment: Hey @EugeneAstafiev Could you please advice on [Word web addin Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data).